# autodoc_pydantic: Show fields from parent model

Tags: python, python-sphinx, pydantic, autodoc, autodoc-pydantic

I'm using the `autodoc_pydantic` plugin for Sphinx to document my `pydantic.BaseModel` classes.  However, there are cases where I have something like

```py
class Foo(pydantic.BaseModel):
    '''Foo class'''

    x: str = pydantic.Field(description='The x.')

class Bar(Foo):
    '''Bar class'''

    y: int = pydantic.Field(description='The y.')
```

My .rst file contains the directive

```
.. automodule:: foo.foo
    :members:
```

When the documentation is generated, only the `y` field is shown for the `Bar` class.  Is there a way to get `autodoc_pydantic` to show both `x` and `y` in `Bar`'s description?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be accomplished via the `:inherited-members:` option:

```
.. automodule:: foo.foo
    :inherited-members: BaseModel
```